# How to redirect program output as its input

Tags: c++, linux, shell, stdout, stdin

I've written a simple C++ program for tutorial purposes.
My goal is to loop it infinitely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "text";

  for(;;) {
    std::string string_object{};
    std::getline(std::cin, string_object);
    std::cout << string_object;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After compilation I run it like this:
`./bin 0>&1`
What I expected to happen is that the "text" that is output to stdout, and it will now become also stdin for the program and it will loop forever. Why doesn't it happen?

Comment: That's not how I/O streams work. Writing to the terminal doesn't put the data into the keyboard input.

Comment: You can use a `std::stringstream` to do such things.

Comment: Exactly why do you want to do this? Sounds fun to achieve and I like the question, but I'm curious if there is an actual use case for this.

Comment: @Barmar could you please make the distinction for me? Isn't it accomplished by redirecting 0>&1?

Comment: @klutt just to better understand I/O operations, sorry xD

Comment: FD1 is connected to `/dev/tty`. So `0>&1` is the same as `0>/dev/tty`. So it redirects stdin to the terminal, which reads from the keyboard.

Comment: But stdin is an input stream, you can't use `>` to redirect it, you should use `<`. But it's the same problem.

Comment: @ziemowit141 I think this can help you. Might even be a duplicate for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383803/writing-to-stdin-and-reading-from-stdout-unix-linux-c-programming Tell me if it is what you're looking for

Comment: @ziemowit141 Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967830/capture-a-functions-standard-output-and-write-it-to-a-file/63968064#63968064

Comment: Hey thank you guys! Someone can close as a duplicate?

Comment: @ziemowit141 _"Someone can close as a duplicate?"_ I could. Which one of the links you want to use as the duplicate? Along with my answer, and if you don't insist to do that via external redirections from the shell, you could use a `std::stringstream::rdbuf()` to redirect both `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Comment: @ziemowit: it's not duplicate; in this case OP wants to see a nice loop I guess.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: you can use a stringstream to loop inside of the program, but the OP specifically wants an endless loop through the external file descriptors.

Comment: @kisch _"you can use a stringstream to loop inside of the program"_ That won't catch outputs / inputs made from other functions which call `std::cout` or `std::cin` directly.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: maybe not. but that wasn't asked for, was it? "My goal is to loop it infinitely." Which my solution does.

Comment: @kisch It would be possible to loop infinitely with my solution as well, I don't see your point.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: OP specifically tried to loop through stdout connected back to stdin externally - that's how I read the question. You solution loops internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to output newlines when printing to `std::cout`, otherwise `std::getline()` won't have any complete line to read.

Improved version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "stars" << std::endl;

  for(;;) {
    std::string string_object;
    std::getline(std::cin, string_object);
    std::cout << string_object << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now try this:

```
./bin >file <file
```

you don't see any output, because it's going to the file. But if you stop the program and look at the file, behold, it's full of

```
stars
stars
stars
stars
```

:-)

Also, the reason that the feedback loop cannot start when you try

```
./bin 0>&1
```

is, that you end up with both stdin and stdout connected to `/dev/tty`
(meaning that you can see the output).

But a TTY device cannot ever close the loop, because it actually consists of two separate channels, one passing the output to the terminal, one passing the terminal input to the process.

If you use a regular file for in- and output, the loop can be closed. Every byte written to the file will be read from it as well, if the stdin of the process is connected to it. That's as long as no other process reads from the file simultaneously, because each byte in a stream can be only read once.

Comment: I fixed my explanation why it's necessary to output std::endl (so getline() sees terminated lines coming in; nothing to do with line-buffering)

Comment: Deleted my first comment, put it in the answer instead, to answer the question more comprehensively.

Comment: fixed explanation concerning special behaviour of TTY deivces (thanks to @user414777)

Comment: Thank you for so much effort. Your example is very precise, and this was the key information for me to fully comprehend the question: "But a TTY device cannot ever close the loop, because it actually consists of two separate channels, one passing the output to the terminal, one passing the terminal input to the process"

Answer (score 0):

Because the stdout and stdin don't create a loop. They may point to the same tty, but a tty is actually two separate channels, one for input and one for output, and they don't loop back into one another.

You can try creating a loop by running your program with its stdin connected to the read end of a *pipe*, and with its stdout to its write end. That will work with `cat`:

```
mkfifo fifo
{ echo text; strace cat; } <>fifo >fifo
...
read(0, "text\n", 131072)               = 5
write(1, "text\n", 5)                   = 5
read(0, "text\n", 131072)               = 5
write(1, "text\n", 5)                   = 5
...
```

**But not with your program**. That's because your program is trying to read *lines*, but its writes are not terminated by a newline. Fixing that and also printing the read line to stderr (so we don't have to use `strace` to demonstrate that anything happens in your program), we get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "text" << std::endl;

  for(;;) {
    std::string string_object{};
    std::getline(std::cin, string_object);
    std::cerr << string_object << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_object << std::endl;
  }
}
```

```
g++ foo.cc -o foo
mkfifo fifo; ./foo <>fifo >fifo
text
text
text
...
```

---

**Note:** the `<>fifo` way of opening a named pipe (fifo) was used in order to open both its read and its write end at once and so avoid blocking. Instead of reopening the fifo from its path, the stdout could simply be dup'ed from the stdin (`prog <>fifo >&0`) or the fifo could be first opened as a different file descriptor, and then the stdin and stdout could be opened without blocking, the first in read-only mode and the second in write-only mode (`prog 3<>fifo <fifo >fifo 3>&-`).

They will all work the same with the example at hand. On Linux, `:|prog >/dev/fd/0` (and `echo text | strace cat >/dev/fd/0`) would also work -- without having to create a named pipe with `mkfifo`.

Comment: You don't actually need a FIFO to close the loop. That just complicates the picture. A simple file is completely sufficient. I demonstrate this in my answer. You're right that a TTY would never be able to close the loop; I should correct my answer in that respect.

Comment: IMHO, it's using a regular file which complicates the picture (besides filling up the disk ;-)). It involves hairy issues of file pointer positions and non-synchronized reads and writes to the same file.

Comment: Yeah, but a FIFO adds an intermediate instance between input and output. Input and output are not *directly* connected. This is was OP wanted to achieve. With a regular file, you have the file contents as a kind of unnecessary side effect. The question asks how to directly feed back the process output to its input; and a regular file is as close it gets (or as I can think of).

Comment: @kisch You're confused -- since you're opening the file twice, you're actually using *two* files refering to the same on-disk inode, and **it's a fluke** that the reads and writes are ordered as expected. (And you also have like a dozen layers between the two open file objects, but that's beside the point). And of course, your example will not work as expected if you're using a single file, opened in read-write mode, with the same file pointer, something which you can emulate with `./bin 1<>file 0<&1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using gcc, I'm going to assume you have `pipe` available.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    std::strcpy(buffer, "test");

    int fd[2];
    ::pipe(fd);
    ::dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    ::close(fd[1]);
    ::dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    ::close(fd[0]);

    ::write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 4);
    while(true) {
        auto const read_bytes = ::read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1024);
        ::write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, read_bytes);
#if 0
        std::cerr.write(buffer, read_bytes);
        std::cerr << "\n\tGot " << read_bytes << " bytes" << std::endl;
#endif
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `#if 0` section can be enabled to get debugging.  I couldn't get it to work with `std::cout` and `std::cin` directly, but somebody who knows more about the low-level stream code could probably tweak this.

Debug output:

```
$ ./io_loop 
test
        Got 4 bytes
test
        Got 4 bytes
test
        Got 4 bytes
test
        Got 4 bytes
^C
```